# Unable to click the submenu in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Mouse hover menu’s does not work. Please see further details below:-

1. When I click start --> I get the submenus.
2. When I click customer submenu--> element not clickable

a. I should be able to go to “Search for Customers” or “Create Top level Customer”

```
<div class="TidyMenu Horizontal" id="mainNav">
    <ul class="level1">
        <li><a class="popout level1" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$mainNav&#39;,&#39;Start&#39;)">Start</a>
            <ul class="level2">
                <li><a class="popout level2" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$mainNav&#39;,&#39;Start\\Customers&#39;)">Customers</a>
                    <ul class="level3">
                        <li><a title="Search for Customers" class="level3" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$mainNav&#39;,&#39;Start\\Customers\\3&#39;)">Search for Customers</a></li>
                        <li><a title="Create Top level Customer" class="level3" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$mainNav&#39;,&#39;Start\\Customers\\8&#39;)">Create Top level Customer</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
<div>
```

Comment: Can you also post what code you tried with?

Comment: I tried with the below code and it did not work. please see the code and correct me if iam wrong.
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

js.ExecuteScript("return $(\"a:contains('Start')\").mouseover();"); // Mouse hover to start menu 

      driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Customers")).Click();

Comment: Added my answer. Lemme know if works.

Answer (score 0):

Use Actions utility to first mouse hover on **Start** and then click on the desired sub menu. Sample code should look like below:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Internal;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

//create Actions object
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
IWebElement menuHoverLink = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[text()='Start']"));
builder.MoveToElement(menuHoverLink);

IWebElement subLink = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Customers"));
builder.MoveToElement(subLink);
builder.Click();
builder.Build().Perform();
```

Lemme know if this helps!

Comment: Actions class is not working. Could you please provide me other way instead of Actions class.

Comment: Also if possible, please post a screenshot of that webpage containing Menu and Submenu.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the keys to move over and click, instead of trying with the mouse coordinates this is with the keyboard.

Please try this

Mousehover:

```
String hover=Keys.chord(Keys.DOWN);
driver.findElement(By.linkText("the text which has to be clicked")).sendKeys(hover);
```

Click:

```
String clickdown=Keys.chord(Keys.ENTER);
driver.findElement(By.linkText("sub menu which has to be clicked")).sendKeys(clickdown);
```